# Does OMP Pragmas nesting have significance?

Tags: openmp, pragma

I'm looking at some code like below (in a reviewer/auditor capacity). The nesting shown below was created with TABS in the source code.

```cxx
#pragma omp parallel
    #pragma omp sections
    {
        #pragma omp section
            p2 = ModularExponentiation((a % p), dp, p);
        #pragma omp section
            q2 = ModularExponentiation((a % q), dq, q);
    }
```

Is the nesting a matter of style? Or does it have significance like in, say, Python?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Nesting is done for reasons of pure aesthetics and code readability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can collapse the first two pragmas into one, and it won't change the semantics, so you can change

```
#pragma omp parallel
#pragma omp sections
```

into

```
#pragma omp parallel sections
```

However, the section pragmas must be nested inside of the sections pragma in order to specify task parallelism.  One example of when you might want to keep them separate is if you want to do two parallel sections right after one another with a barrier in between, such as:

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
  #pragma omp sections
  {
    #pragma omp section
    { ... }
    #pragma omp section
    { ... }
  }
  #pragma omp sections
  {
    #pragma omp section
    { ... }
    #pragma omp section
    { ... }
  }
}
```

This will not need to create a new "team" for the second set of sections

Comment: Thanks Matt. Could you provide a reference since my attempts to search have been pretty fruitless? Can I use spaces to create the nesting? Or does it have to be tabs? I'm out of upvotes at the moment, so you will have to wait until tonight for the upvote.

Comment: Check out the "Sections" section of this site: http://bisqwit.iki.fi/story/howto/openmp/#Sections.  Syntax is not indentation sensitive, so spaces should be fine.

Comment: @jww, OpenMP for C and C++ is implemented as a set of pragmas. Each pragma is a separate OpenMP construct. The scope of most OpenMP constructs is the code that immediately follows them, including any pragmas it might contain. If the code consists of more than one statement, it should be enclosed in `{ ... }` as usual. The nesting rules are defined by the standard, e.g. `section` should be inside `sections` and `sections` works when inside `parallel` (either lexically or dynamically).

Comment: @jww The definitive reference is the appropriate OpenMP standard document, which you can download from http://openmp.org/wp/openmp-specifications/